# Disable views and controllers in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

i want to implement an api-only rails app, which serves some json content, with GRAPE, the api gem. as i don't need the functionality of views and controllers, i'm wondering if i can disable these two functionalities. any advice? or should i just ignore them because they don't use much ram and ressources anyway?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

there are several resources on the web that show how a minimal rails setup can look like. have a look at the railscast modularity episode: http://railscasts.com/episodes/349-rails-modularity

Answer (score 2):

As you mention, it's definitly worth to disable unused components, which increases speed and reduces RAM consumption.
Heres an interesting [post](http://pivotallabs.com/users/jdean/blog/articles/1419-building-a-fast-lightweight-rest-service-with-rails-3-) abbout it.
Better than that there is also special version of rails designed to satisfy such kind of needs: [rails-api](https://github.com/spastorino/rails-api)

Comment: Link points to 404, [here](http://pivotallabs.com/building-a-fast-lightweight-rest-service-with-rails-3-/) is the current one